# How to test Play Framework APIs and perform Unit Testing over it?

Tags: python, playframework

I need to test some API created in Python Play Framework. While using PHP I used Postman, what is the similar tool to be used to check Play API's?

Comment: The Play Framework is Java/Scala (as it says in the tag); did you mistakenly put Python in the question and the tag or are you talking about a different framework (possibly a port of Play to python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in testing REST servers, you can use Postman with Play as with node.js or your PHP server